# *ngIf & Object.keys()

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

Why I can't use `Object.keys()` method inside an `*ngIf` directive of Angular?
WebStorm arises *Unresolved variable or type Object* error, highlighting the "Object" word.

Example:

```
<span *ngIf="Object.keys(item).includes('author')">
```

Edit:
I appreciate the answers; I knew how to make it work (so for example using a function created in the .ts with the Object.keys() method and returning true or false), but my question was why can't this code be directly used ***inside the *ngIf***, because everytime I write the word "Object" inside the *ngIf expression, WebStorm claims that error I mentioned.

Comment: you can use `*ngIf="item['author']!==undefined"`

Answer (score 2):

Like for `enum`, you need to make the reference public in your component to make it accessible in the angular template :

```
class MyComponent {
    public Object = Object
}
```

Anyway for your particular problem I'd created a [custom pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#creating-pipes-for-custom-data-transformations) instead of calling this method in the template directly.

Answer (score 1):

use a getter variable

```
get checkValue(){
    return Object.keys(item).includes('author') 
}

 <span *ngIf="checkValue">
```